# Google plugin for Eclipse - Eclipse fails to launch

Tags: eclipse, gwt, workbench

I seem to have successfully downloaded the Google plugin (v4.2) for Eclipse from:
http://www.gwtproject.org/usingeclipse.html

Following the download, I tick yes to restart Eclipse for the plugin to take effect.

It kills my current session of Eclipse, and then attempts a restart of Eclipse, but only gets as far as asking me to specify a new workspace, following the splash screen (Android Developer Tools black/green start up screen).

Then it displays the following error message:
An error has occurred. See the log file

I cannot open Eclipse from this point on.

Steps I've taken so far to rectify this issue:
- tried keeping the same workspace when prompted to specify
- tried making a new workspace when prompted to specify
- starting Eclipse through command prompt with -clean
- Deleting workbench.xmi from .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench
- Deleting .snap from .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/ *file didn't exist*

*When I found no solution, I did a complete reinstall of Eclipse. My workspace and past projects worked fine following the reinstall. Everything is hunkydory until I try to install the Google plugin again. Same result happened second time around*

Here is the last section of the log file for this event:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2014-02-04 16:24:05.633
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.CommandServiceAddon' from bundle '142'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager to org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager to org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.get(EclipseContext.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.CommandServiceAddon.init(CommandServiceAddon.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    ... 27 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2014-02-04 16:24:05.643
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.CommandProcessingAddon' from bundle '155'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "CommandProcessingAddon.commandService": no actual value was found for the argument "ECommandService".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2014-02-04 16:24:05.651
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon' from bundle '158'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "BindingProcessingAddon.commandService": no actual value was found for the argument "ECommandService".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-02-04 16:24:05.869
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.processHierarchy(E4Workbench.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.init(E4Workbench.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.(E4Workbench.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

Comment: Is the Eclipse 4.2 or 4.3 you are running? If it is 4.3 you need the 4.3 version of the Google plugin.

Comment: I'm running Eclipse 4.2 and downloaded Google plugin 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously, I was downloading the ADT SDK bundle from the official android site. This only gives you Eclipse 4.2, not 4.3. I therefore initially had to download 4.2 version of Google plugin to match up with my Eclipse version- this is where I was getting the error outlined above.

**Here was my fix:**

Instead of downloading the ADT SDK bundle, I did a fresh download of Eclipse only, then added the SDK tools/ADT plugin/platform tools/platform/system image separately. From the official Eclipse site, I could download Eclipse 4.3.

Then I downloaded Google plugin 4.3. It just seemed to work fine. So there seemed to be a problem with the Eclipse 4.2 and Google plugin 4.2 combo.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem as you and I think I might be forced to uninstall and reinstall the whole of Eclipse. I had installed google plugin for eclipse 4.2 for my eclipse 4.2 and now I keep on getting the error message with the long metadata log.

I'm surprised that this bug is not discussed on FAQ on google's site. This is really frustrating and I wish I found this thread before I blindly trusted the google plugin to work without issues.